# If I go out of activities where there is a timer turns it off

Tags: java, android

When I go out from activity where is timer the timer is still going. How to make himself stop after leaving the activity?

This is my code:

```
   new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {//CountDownTimer(edittext1.getText()+edittext2.getText()) also parse it to long

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textView.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Intent myIntent=new Intent(hra1.this, timeout.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
            .start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare your countdown timer before your `onCreate` method

```
CountDownTimer myTimer;
```

Where you are making new CountdownTimer, do it like this

```
myTimer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) // etc
```

write these lines in your `onPause` method

```
myTimer.cancel();
myTimer = null;
```

Comment: how can i create onPauce method?

Comment: @noro right click your code and select "Source" > "Override/implement methods" and under the Activity tab there should be a onPause() method, check it and click OK and Eclipse will generate the code for you.

Comment: where is the problem @noro

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

          public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
              super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
              // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
          }
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textView.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext 
        } 

        public void onFinish() { 
            Intent myIntent=new Intent(hra1.this, timeout.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        } 
    }
```

create timer object

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(15000, 1000);
```

to start timer

```
countDownTimer.start();
```

to stop timer

```
countDownTimer.cancel();
```

stop timer at `onPause` method